# How do you fit a group level regression for a multilevel model using the lme4 package in R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

How do you fit a multilevel regression model in R where you want to include a group-level regression? I think that the answer is using STAN, but I've been trying to use lmer() from the lme4 package.

Say you have data on radon levels in houses within counties. You have a house-level predictor "Dust" and a county-level measure of "Uranium" and "Plutonium."

County level: $ \alpha_j \sim N\big (\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 plut_j + \gamma_2 uran_j, \sigma^2_{alpha}\big)$

House level: $radon_i = \alpha_{j[i]} + \beta dust_i + \epsilon_i$

How would you fit a model at the county level, like the following:
county ~ uranium + plutonium
and then incorporate the new county coefficients in the first model?

Comment: If there's only one value of uranium per county then there's really not a separate `county ~ uranium` model and you could just use `lmer(radon ~ dust + (1|uranium))`.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question (fit the country level model, then the MLM ??). You have one level-1 predictor "Dust" and one level-2 predictor "Uranium". I believe you want a full MLM with random intercepts but not random slopes.
`lmer(radon ~ dust + uranium + (1|country), data= df, REML=TRUE)` Or are you asking for something else? Can you please specify what fixed effects and what random effects you want?